# How to highlight two elements at the same time time in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, highlight

I have the following code in selenium:

I want to highlight two elements at the same time but not able to do so, Can any one suggest why not???

```
 string highlightJavascript2 = @"$(arguments[0]).css({ ""border-width"" : ""4px"", ""border-style"" : ""solid"", ""border-color"" : ""#FF0000"" });";
                                       jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript2, new object[] { DOB_List[i] ,Dependent_Name_List[i]});
```

Where DOB list and dependent name list are both list of the elements.

Comment: How do you do it manually?

Comment: No by using the code automatically. Is something like that possible?? I am trying to see but not able to do.

Comment: What kotoj is trying to say is... how do you do this manually? The point being, mirror what is done manually in code and it should work.

Comment: yes jeffc exactly, will u help me??